# Crystal Reports 8.5 stopped working - failed to export the report (to PDF)

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, report

Crystal Reports 8.5 installation has functioned fine for 10+ years. Suddenly, with no obvious change, the export function has stopped working.

Have isolated to problem to CR itself and it has nothing to do with VBA integration. A simple test report was created in the designer. Preview works, print to paper works. Export to PDF (Diskfile) results in error "Failed to export the report". The same goes for all kind of reports the system generates in the background.

CR: 8.5
OS: Win2000
Internet: NO

The system has not been patched for a long time and the problem arose last week.

What could that be..?

Comment: Re-installed Crystal Reports without any progress..

Comment: Completly removed product and re-installed. Still not working.

Comment: Also tried the same install on a virtual XP machine. That works just fine. Something broken in win2000?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue--previously working installation, no changes to the system, sudden failure. I spent all day looking up DLLs and service packs that don't exist anymore. But no, just empty your temp folder. I don't know why, but that's it. For an application so bad at cleaning up after itself, crw32 gets touchy about temp being full.